# Layout inflater issue only occurs some specific devices

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, inflate-exception

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

code:

```
public class QuestionOptionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final Context context;
    private final boolean viewQuestion;
    List<QuestionOption> optionList;
    private String questionId;
    String type = "";
    private Dialog dialog = null;
    private boolean answer = false;
    private boolean isFinshed;
    private Question mQuestion;
    private static final int NOT_SELECTED = -1;
    private int selectedPos = NOT_SELECTED;
    boolean isClicked = false;
    protected DialogManager alertDialog;
    protected ExamGuruApplication.Listener mListener;
    private int pos ;
    private boolean isShowError ;

    public QuestionOptionsAdapter(Context context, List<QuestionOption> optionList, String questionId, boolean viewQuestion, String type, boolean answer, boolean isFinshed, Question mQuestion, ExamGuruApplication.Listener mListener, int position, boolean isShowError) {
        this.context = context;
//        this.mFragment = mFragment;
        this.isFinshed = isFinshed;
        this.viewQuestion = viewQuestion;
        this.optionList = null;
        this.optionList = optionList;
        this.questionId = questionId;
        this.mQuestion = mQuestion;
        this.mListener = mListener;
        this.pos = position;
        this.type = type;
        this.isShowError = isShowError;
        this.answer = answer;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return optionList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return optionList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView != null) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.option_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        alertDialog = DialogManager.getInstance();
        QuestionOption option = optionList.get(position);
        holder.option_correct_incorrect_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(false);
        holder.optionText.setText(option.getEntry() + ".");
        holder.option_radio_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (selectedPos != position) {
                    if (!isFinshed) {
                        isClicked = true;
                        answerMarking(position);
                        setSelection(position);
                        mListener.isClicked();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        boolean isCame = false;
        if(ExamGuruApplication.getTutorList().get(pos) != null && !ExamGuruApplication.getTutorList().get(pos)) {
            if ((!mQuestion.getLocked() && type.equals("tutor")) && !isFinshed && option.getEntry() != null && mQuestion.getSelectedOption() != null && option.getId().equals(mQuestion.getSelectedOption().getId()) && ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().get(pos) == null) {
                ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().put(pos, position);
                mQuestion.getSelectedOption().setId(0);
            }
            if ((!mQuestion.getLocked() && type.equals("tutor")) && !isFinshed && ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().containsKey(pos) && ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().get(pos) != null) {
                if (ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().get(pos) == position) {
                    holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(true);
                    System.out.println("one");
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    isCame = true;
                } else {
                    holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(false);
                    isCame = false;
                }
            }
        }else if(ExamGuruApplication.getTutorList().get(pos) != null && ExamGuruApplication.getTutorList().get(pos)){
            if (ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight() != null && ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().size() >0  && ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().get(pos) != null && ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().get(pos) == position) {
                holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(true);
                System.out.println("two");
                if(ExamGuruApplication.getTutorList().get(pos) != null && ExamGuruApplication.getTutorList().get(pos)) {
                    holder.option_correct_incorrect_image.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wrong));
                    holder.option_correct_incorrect_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }else{
            if (!isFinshed && option.getEntry() != null && mQuestion.getSelectedOption() != null && option.getId().equals(mQuestion.getSelectedOption().getId()) && ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().get(pos) == null) {
                ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().put(pos, position);
                mQuestion.getSelectedOption().setId(0);
            }
            if (!isFinshed && ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().containsKey(pos) && ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().get(pos) != null) {
                if (ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().get(pos) == position) {
                    holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(true);
//                    System.out.println("showError "+ExamGuruApplication.getShowErrorList().get(position) != null ? ExamGuruApplication.getShowErrorList().get(position): false);
                    if(ExamGuruApplication.getShowErrorList().get(position) != null && ExamGuruApplication.getShowErrorList().get(position) && mQuestion.getLocked()){
                        holder.option_correct_incorrect_image.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wrong));
                        holder.option_correct_incorrect_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    System.out.println("three");
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    isCame = true;
                } else {
                    holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(false);
                    isCame = false;
                }
            }
        }
        holder.optionDescription.setText(option.getDetails());
        holder.optionDescription.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (selectedPos != position) {
                    if (!isFinshed) {
                        isClicked = true;
                        answerMarking(position);
                        setSelection(position);
                        mListener.isClicked();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        if (isFinshed) {
            holder.option_radio_btn.setClickable(false);
        }

        if (mQuestion.getIsLocked()) {
            holder.optionDescription.setClickable(false);
            holder.optionDescription.setEnabled(false);
            holder.option_radio_btn.setClickable(false);
            holder.option_radio_btn.setEnabled(true);
        }

        if (option != null && option.getCorrect() != null && answer && option.getCorrect()) {
            if (isFinshed && !isClicked || mQuestion.getIsLocked()) {
                setSelection(position);
                holder.option_correct_incorrect_image.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.right));
                holder.option_correct_incorrect_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (!isFinshed) {
                    if (!viewQuestion) {
//                        answerMarking(position);
                    }
                }
                if (mQuestion.getSelectedOption() != null) {
                    if (option.getId().equals(mQuestion.getSelectedOption().getId())) {
                        System.out.println("four");
                        holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(true);
                    }else{
                        holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
                holder.optionDescription.setClickable(false);
                holder.optionDescription.setEnabled(false);
                holder.option_radio_btn.setClickable(false);
                holder.option_radio_btn.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        if (mQuestion != null && !isCame) {
            if (!isFinshed && mQuestion.getSelectedOption() != null && !mQuestion.getIsLocked()) {
                if(position ==0 && option.getId().equals(mQuestion.getSelectedOption().getId())){
                    holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (option.getEntry() != null && option.getId().equals(mQuestion.getSelectedOption().getId())) {
                    if (!isFinshed && !isClicked) {
                        if (!viewQuestion) {
//                            answerMarking(position);
//                            setSelection(position);
                            if (!isClicked) {
                                holder.optionDescription.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.BLACK));
                                holder.optionText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.BLACK));
                                System.out.println("=========" + position + "=========" + selectedPos);
                                System.out.println("five");
//                                holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(true);
                                isClicked = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (isFinshed && mQuestion.getSelectedOption() != null || mQuestion.getIsLocked()) {
                if (mQuestion.getSelectedOption() != null && option.getId().equals(mQuestion.getSelectedOption().getId())) {
                    if (option.getCorrect() != null && !option.getCorrect()) {
                        holder.option_correct_incorrect_image.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wrong));
                        holder.option_correct_incorrect_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(true);
                        System.out.println("six");
                        holder.option_radio_btn.setClickable(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (position == selectedPos && isClicked) {
            holder.optionDescription.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.BLACK));
            holder.optionText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.BLACK));
            System.out.println("=========" + position + "=========" + selectedPos);
            holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(true);
            System.out.println("seven");
        } else if (isClicked) {
            holder.optionDescription.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.BLACK));
            holder.optionText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.BLACK));
            System.out.println("========="+position+"========="+selectedPos);
            holder.option_radio_btn.setChecked(false);
        }
        final View ref = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holderRef = holder;

//        ExamGuruApplication.setHeight(ExamGuruApplication.getHeight()+holder.optionDescription.getHeight() );
        return convertView;
    }

    // if called with the same position multiple lines it works as toggle
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        if (selectedPos == position) {
            selectedPos = NOT_SELECTED;
        } else {
            selectedPos = position;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        private TextView optionText;
        private TextView optionDescription;
        private TextView option_correct_incorrect_image;
        private RadioButton option_radio_btn;
        int distanceFromTop;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            optionText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.option_text);
            optionDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.option_description);
            option_correct_incorrect_image = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.option_correct_incorrect_image);
            option_radio_btn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.option_radio_btn);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates and displays a progress dialog if one does not already exist
     */
    protected void showProgressDialog() {
        try {
            if (dialog == null) {
                dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.CustomProgressTheme);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                dialog.show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Dismiss Progress Dialog
     */
    protected void dismissProgressDialog() {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        dialog = null;
    }

    private void answerMarking(final int position) {
        MarkedAnswers mMarkedAnswers = new MarkedAnswers();
        mMarkedAnswers.setId(optionList.get(position).getId().toString());
        mMarkedAnswers.setIsGuessed(false);
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("timed")) {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long seconds = (endTime - ExamGuruApplication.getStartTime()) / 1000;
            mMarkedAnswers.setAnsweringTime((int) seconds);
        }
//        showProgressDialog();
        ExamGuruManger.getInstance().markedQuestionAnswer(mMarkedAnswers, String.valueOf(UserPreferences.getId()), questionId, new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
//                dismissProgressDialog();
                ExamGuruApplication.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                SelectedOption mSelectedOption = new SelectedOption();
                mSelectedOption.setId(optionList.get(position).getId());
                mSelectedOption.setDetails(optionList.get(position).getDetails());
                mSelectedOption.setEntry(optionList.get(position).getEntry());
                mQuestion.setSelectedOption(mSelectedOption);
                ExamGuruApplication.getListHeight().put(pos, position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
//                dismissProgressDialog();
                alertDialog.showDialog(context, "", error.getLocalizedMessage(), context.getString(R.string.alert_ok), "");
            }
        });
    }

    public void notifyChanged() {
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Above mentioned inflater service only creating problem in Android 6.0.1, samsung S6 device only.Other devices working as expected.

Exception:

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
       at com.comquest.adapter.QuestionOptionsAdapter.(SourceFile:68)
       at com.comquest.fragment.ViewPagerFragment$5.success(SourceFile:654)
       at com.comquest.fragment.ViewPagerFragment$5.success(SourceFile:648)
       at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(SourceFile:45)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Note : This log detected by using crashlytics from user end.

Comment: Post the logcat too.

Comment: @KNeerajLal Updated the log.

Comment: Where is this code written? Need to see more code.

Comment: post full code of your `Activity`..

Comment: @KNeerajLal now you can see my code

Comment: Are you init adapter in fragment and pass context into adapter with getActivity() in fragment?

Comment: you can remove your inflater, and use this code ```convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout. option_list_item, null, false);``` inside view method.

Comment: @Boopathi What are you passing as context to `QuestionOptionsAdapter`?

Comment: @KNeerajLal i am passing getActivity().

Comment: @Boopathi There seems to be a condition where the context passed is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your log, It's very straightforward check that you will only get null inflater if your context will be null. So try to check context before initialising inflater

```
if(context!=null){
   inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}else{
//Get the context from Application class if you have already. Or Create Application class which could give global application context
context = YourApplication.getContext(); 
 // getContext would be user-defined method in your application class
 inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: After trying this are you still getting null pointer on inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

and use ApplicationContext insted of activity context when you construct 'QuestionOptionsAdapter'